# how to get current windows user from express?

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent

Hi I am new to Nodejs and express framework.

I am implementing a simple CRUD application, and users are expecting to visit the page from MS windows. I wish to log down the current windows user name.

I've tried logging the User-Agent string on the page, and it seems User-Agent does not contain the windows user name. Is this true? and what is the right way to implement this?

```
res.render('search', {user: req.get('User-Agent')});
```

Then in jade,

```
body
    p welcome, #{user}!
```

Here is what i got:

```
Welcome, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36!
```

Comment: You need NTLM authentication.

Comment: Thanks, SLaks. is this required for authentication only or it is required even just for reading current login user name?

Comment: All you need is [express-ntlm](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `User-Agent` doesn't include the windows username. Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) for further information.

A possible solution to your problem may be a NTLM Authentication. To add this install and optionally save [express-ntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm) as a dependency:

```
npm install express-ntlm [--save]
```

Then require and add it as a middleware to express:

```
var ntlm = require('express-ntlm');
app.use(ntlm());
```

You will then be able to use the `UserName` in jade:

```
body
    p welcome, #{ntlm.UserName}!
```

In case you want to do a *real* NTLM Authentication and validate the credentials using an Active Directory you can do this as well:

```
app.use(ntlm({
    domain: 'MYDOMAIN',
    domaincontroller: 'ldap://myad.example',
}));
```

Comment: ===================== app.js =====================
app.use('/', routes);
app.use(ntlm());
app.use('/search', search);
===================== search.js ===================== res.render('search', {
             user:req.ntlm.UserName
                });        
});

Hi @Fabio, I guess I am confused with the routing here. What should I write in this case if i want ntlm() to run for http://localhost:3000/search

Comment: Middlewares are executed by they order they are defined. So in your setup it should work. It's not needed to explicitely define `user` since `ntlm.UserName` is available to the rendering context (see my jade example).

Comment: app.use('/', routes);
var ntlm = require('express-ntlm');
app.use(ntlm()); 
app.use('/search', search);

This gives me a 401 error.

in chrome console: 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNEXPECTED
search:1 GET http://localhost:3000/search net::ERR_UNEXPECTED
search:1 GET http://localhost:3000/search net::ERR_UNEXPECTED

Comment: hi, @Fabio Poloni, I am revisiting the problem. thanks for your previous suggestions. I now realized the problem i have is probably complicated. I re-post my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183444/how-to-use-express-ntlm-to-get-windows-user-name-without-authentication-using-no

I just saw that you are actually a contributor to express-ntlm lib. wow!

Do you have any idea why my request.connection.ntlm is null? thanks.