# how to use express-ntlm to get windows user name without authentication using NODE.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-ntlm

I am trying to use express-ntlm to get windows user name without authentication.

in my app.js, i put the following:

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
var ntlm = require('express-ntlm'); 
app.use(ntlm()); 
app.use('/search', search);
```

This gives me a 401 error in node.js when loading http://localhost:3000/search
In chrome console: Failed to load resource: 
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNEXPECTED

what is the correct sequence of routing here?
thanks.

========= modified to ==============

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var TT = require('./routes/TT');
var KYEC_stat = require('./routes/KYEC_stat');
var ftc = require('./routes/ftc');
var volPerDevice = require('./routes/topVolPerDevice');
var search = require('./routes/search');

var ntlm = require('express-ntlm'); 
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(ntlm()); 
app.use('/search', search);
app.use('/tt', TT);
app.use('/kyec', KYEC_stat);
app.use('/ftc', ftc);
app.use('/vol', volPerDevice);
app.use('/', routes);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

======= topVolPerDevice.js ================

```
var config = require('../config.json');
var express = require('express');
var query = require('pg-query');
var assert = require('assert');
var async = require('async');
var url = require('url');
var queryString = require('querystring');

var router = express.Router();


/* Display quantity tested per device id since 2011 using d3 */
/* The query will first select all lot records and their earliest test date (which is the 'P' insertion incoming material quantity);
   then use {lotid, lotstartdate} to retrieve all 1st insertion lot records, then add up lots per device;
   then return the 1st 20 device id which tops inocming material quantity;
 */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        query.connectionParameters = config.reportConnStr;      //connecting to localhost
        var deviceArray = new Array();
        var sqlstr =  "sdfsfdfsdsfds";
        query(sqlstr, function(err, rows, result) {
            assert.equal(rows, result.rows);
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var device = {};
                device.name = rows[i].device;
                device.value = rows[i].totalqtyout;
                deviceArray.push(device);        
            }
            res.render('d3t1', {deviceArray:deviceArray});                      
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

===== update 2/25/2015 =============

I am re-visiting the problem this week, and I reached a little bit further.
I tried to put down a few debug statements in express-ntlm.js and also installed firebug in firefox. It turns out that it is probably not about the sequence of middleware.

```
return function(request, response, next) {
    if (!request.connection.id) {
        request.connection.id = utils.uuidv4();
    }

    var auth_headers = request.headers.authorization;

    var user = request.connection.ntlm;
....
}
```

over here, my request.connection.ntlm is null.

What could be the reason here? is it about browser settings or my network settings?

I am running this over company network, and I am on a network domain.

[image]

Comment: updates in original question.

Comment: Actually, it's no problem that `request.connection.ntlm` is null. This is to check, wether the connection is already authenticated or not.

Comment: Could you try this basic setup? `var express = require('express'),
    ntlm = require('express-ntlm');

var app = express();

app.use(ntlm());

app.all('*', function(request, response) {
    response.end(JSON.stringify(request.ntlm));
});

app.listen(80);`

Comment: Hi @Fabio, I tried. It wouldn't reach the app.all() part.

Comment: The code will execute to 
       handle_type1(...)
 =>  connect_to_proxy(...) 
=>   proxy.negotiate(...) 
and then go to the callback of connect_to_proxy(...), which simply sets the status code to 401 and end response.

is this signalling a failure somewhere?

Comment: HTTP status-code 401 is "Unauthorized", which means that the user is not authorized at this moment. If it sets the status to 401 and ends the response, it seems to be working as expected. Could you log the `challenge.toString('base64')` to the console on line [express-ntlm.js#L149](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm/blob/master/lib/express-ntlm.js#L149)? This would help to see wether there's an error in `express-ntlm` or your browser. Btw. what OS and browser do you use?

Comment: Hi @FabioPoloni, thanks. i just attached the firebug screen capture. would it be sufficient?

Comment: I am using win + chrome; I also tried firefox.

Comment: Your screenshot show the NTLM Negotiation Request and the NTLM Challnege Response, which is `NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAAAAoAAABggAAASNFZ4mrze8AAAAAAAAAAA==`.

Comment: Please add `console.log('NTLM Authentication Result:', result);` on line [express-ntlm.js#L171](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm/blob/master/lib/express-ntlm.js#L171).

Comment: >nodemon
27 Feb 16:20:32 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
27 Feb 16:20:32 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
27 Feb 16:20:32 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
27 Feb 16:20:32 - [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
[express-ntlm] No Authorization header present
GET /search 401 5ms
[express-ntlm] No domaincontroller was specified, all Authentication messages are valid.
challenge.toString('base64') = TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAAAAoAAABggAAASNFZ4mrze8AAAAAA
AAAAA==
GET /search 401 2ms

Comment: Could you try the basic setup from above?

Comment: Hi, @Fabio, are you referring to line 171. I tried but it didn't reach there. The above is print out from L149.

Comment: Sorry, my background on NTLM is zero. Is the 401 http response considered a challenge to browser and chrome should reply with an answer whose header contains a NTLM uSer name and domain?

Comment: NTLM in very basic words: Browser makes a request, server answers with 401 and tells him to authenticate using NTLM. Browser tries again, this time with a NTLM message (just information). Server answers with a 401 (again!) and gives him a challenge. Browser now finally sends him an authentication with username and so on. Server validates (only with domain controller set!) the login, extracts user information and answers with the requested ressource and most likely a 200 OK.

Comment: So in this case, my browser received the 2nd 401 response, but didn't make any answer?

Comment: In that case there must be a problem in your browser *or* you just don't see the response. It's hard to debug the NTLM protocol, because most browser will only show the resulting request/response instead of the whole flow.

Comment: thanks for the information, @FabioPoloni

the discussion is probably too long to read. I have continued the question to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825549/how-to-use-fiddler-to-debug-ntlm-protocol-with-chrome

Comment: I recently discovered a [bug](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm/issues/8) using NTLM Authentication in Windows 10 (and probably Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 as well).

Answer (score 0):

---

UPDATE:

Change to this in the app.js:

```
app.use(ntlm()); 
app.use('/', search);
app.use('/', TT);
app.use('/', KYEC_stat);
app.use('/', ftc);
app.use('/', volPerDevice);
app.use('/', routes);
```

And add '/vol' in the router in the topVolPerDevice file:

```
var config = require('../config.json');
var express = require('express');
var query = require('pg-query');
var assert = require('assert');
var async = require('async');
var url = require('url');
var queryString = require('querystring');

var router = express.Router();


/* Display quantity tested per device id since 2011 using d3 */
/* The query will first select all lot records and their earliest test date (which is the 'P' insertion incoming material quantity);
   then use {lotid, lotstartdate} to retrieve all 1st insertion lot records, then add up lots per device;
   then return the 1st 20 device id which tops inocming material quantity;
 */
router.get('/vol', function(req, res) {
        query.connectionParameters = config.reportConnStr;      //connecting to localhost
        var deviceArray = new Array();
        var sqlstr =  "sdfsfdfsdsfds";
        query(sqlstr, function(err, rows, result) {
            assert.equal(rows, result.rows);
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var device = {};
                device.name = rows[i].device;
                device.value = rows[i].totalqtyout;
                deviceArray.push(device);        
            }
            res.render('d3t1', {deviceArray:deviceArray});                      
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: thanks, MrBearAndBeer.
I re-posted my question with the recommended edit, however, it still shows 
GET /search 401 5ms

any idea?

Comment: can you show me the just the code of one route file?

Comment: thanks again, MrBearAndBeer. I re-posted with my routes JavaScript.

Comment: @sqr can you share all the app with github or send to my email?

Comment: @sqr see my update answer.. i try to update the question instead of my answer, sorry..

Comment: sorry for the late reply!
I just tried what you recommended; and it still doesn't work.

Comment: interestingly, i noticed that if i type http://localhost:3000/vol in firefox ( i was using chrome), it will prompt me with a login message box, saying 'Enter username and password for http://localhost:3000

is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @sqr Yes, this is supposed to happen, because Firefox doesn't support NTLM as Chrome does.